# Arduino upload error "stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding" in Fedora

Tags: linux, ide, arduino

I am attempting to upload the stock *Blink* sketch using the Arduino IDE in Fedora Core 15 Linux. I get this error:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

To recreate the issue:

1. Plug in the Arduino Uno board via USB cable
2. Open the Arduino IDE
3. Menu *File* → *Examples* → *1. Basics* → *Blink*
4. Menu *Tools* → *Serial Port* → then check the box for */dev/ttyACM0*
5. Menu *Tools* → *Board* → *Arduino Uno*
6. Click the "Play" button to Verify/Compile (this step is successful)
7. Click the *Upload* button, to get the error

I tried these same exact steps in Windows XP, and the upload was successful, so I must not have Fedora configured correctly.

I followed the [Arduino Playground instructions](http://arduino.cc/playground/Linux/Fedora), installing the client using `yum` and adding my user ID to the groups *uucp*, *lock* and *dialout*.

I did **not** follow the *RXTX fixup -- Link the proper files* part of the guide, since the given command did not return any matches: `find ~ -name librxtxSerial.so -o -name RXTXcomm.jar | grep -v Download`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question was posted, a new stable version of Arduino has been released.  They are now on 1.0, and it works in Fedora Core Linux 16.  It can be downloaded here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Answer (score 9):

Before uploading your programme, make sure you selected the right board type, from menu *Tools* → *Board*.

Comment: Ran into this same issue and, in my case, my board is a generic _ATmega328P Arduino Compatible Nano V3_ I got online, which has a mini USB interface. Pin 13's LED blinks nicely on reset, which suggests it comes with a bootloader. I kept trying multiple board types including _Arduino Mini_, but only until I chose _Arduino Mini_ _**Pro**_ was I finally able to upload the sketch. Good to go now.

Comment: Arduino Pro Mini also worked for me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

Check if you have any jumpers connected to the digital pins 0 or 1. Those pins have also serial communication functions. And because you are uploading on the Arduino board, using the serial connection provided by the USB cable, you don't want the board's serial port to be engaged in other activities via pins 0 or 1.

Comment: This solved my issue too. I had digital pins 0 and 1 connected to gates of N-Channel MOSFET's, and this was enough to stop the Arduino programming.

Comment: same here. i had pin 0 and 1 connected to another shield. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, go to menu *Tools* → *Processor* and change to ATMega328P (Old Bootloader). Then the problem is solved.

But make sure that you do the [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) before upload:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Re *"Processor"*: Don't you mean *"Programmer"*?

Comment: Isn't that chmod a bit risky? Isn't it allowing everybody access? Can't it be achieved by [including the current user in the "dialup" group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/read-write-to-a-serial-port-without-root/14363#14363)?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it was probably caused by [a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=726919) that was present in [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) at the time. A simple `yum update AVRDUDE` should now fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, changing the cable worked.

I was using [Ubuntu 17.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.04_.28Zesty_Zapus.29) (Zesty Zapus), Arduino Nano with ATmega28 and a USB cable with ferrite choke (I don’t think ferrite choke was the cause).

Comment: No, bad USB cables are a very common source of error.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Uno R3, Mac OS X v10.8.3 (Mountain Lion), any version of Arduino.app. For me changing the USB cable fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the instruction in *[Why I can't upload my programs to the Arduino board?](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload)* that says

> On Linux, the Uno and Mega 2560 show up as devices of the form
>   /dev/ttyACM0

does not always apply. In my [Ubuntu 14.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.10_.28Utopic_Unicorn.29) (Utopic Unicorn) I can see that port in menu *Tools* → *Serial Port*, but when selected and trying to upload to the Arduino Nano V3 I get the error

> stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

**Changing the Tools -> Serial Port to /dev/ttyUSB0 solves the problem.**

I'm guessing that this may be the case in my system where I had an other device at the same USB port before plugging Arduino there. It may be that after restart the situation might be different; I don't know haven't tested. But whatever is the cause, the good news is that the problem can be solved.

**You can easily check what is the correct serial port by first checking what ports are available without plugging the Arduino (menu *Tools* → *Serial Port*) and then checking again what is the added port after plugging the Arduino in the USB port.**

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me:

**If you have a USBasp programmer (or other type of ICSP programmer) plugged into your Arduino** board (but not plugged into your PC), because you just used it to flash the bootloader of your Arduino board, **unplug it from the Arduino**. Disconnecting the 5V line between the USBasp programmer and the Arduino was enough for me. Now uploading works (with the USBasp programmer lying on the bench with all but the 5V pin still connected to the Arduino).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, the problem has been solved:

Choose menu *Tools* → *Programmer* → *Arduino as ISP*

Comment: Are you sure about that? Why would it matter for normal use what it is set to? Isn't it only for burning a boot loader, etc. (using the required extra hardware for that)?

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, I tried doing this

- In PowerShell, run `devcon status usb*`. This should show multiple devices similar, one among which would be

  ```
  USB\VID_2341&PID_8036&MI_00\6&1D9C3F6B&0&0000
      Name: Arduino Leonardo (COM3)
      Driver is running.
  ```
- Then do `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_2341&PID_8036&MI_00\6&1D9C3F6B&0&0000\Device Parameters" /v "PortName" /t REG_SZ /d "COM3" /f.`. Double check `COM3` is also listed in [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) menu of windows.
- Restart the machine and the Arduino IDE. And try uploading again.