# avrdude: stk500_recv():programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino

I bought a new Arduino Ethernet Shield and connect it to Arduino Uno. When I uploaded my code, I got the error avrdude: stk500_recv():programmer is not responding. Without the Ethernet Shield, it could run succeed. I have tried all the solutions on the Internet. Mac os 10.10.5 and Arduino 1.6.10. The board I chose is Arduino Uno and serial port is dev/cu.usbmodem1421. I have tried to reset and reinstall Arduino IDE，and downloaded FTDI driver. These solutions are not working.

Comment: Move this to the Arduino stack exchange..but that error is telling you the programmer can't upload the program. That is due to either, having the wrong programmer selected, or if none is selected, meaning it's using the USB connection. Which are you using?

Comment: Are you using the Arduino IDE or something else? ......read this solution...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562349/arduino-upload-error-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-responding-in-fedora?rq=1...which you could have found by googling

Comment: I have used AVR ISP as my programmer, and I changed it to Arduino as ISP, but they are not working either.

Comment: Yes I used Arduino IDE. I read this solution and tried all the methods it mentioned. None of them worked. So I want to post my problem here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are getting this error because one of these two problems.

1. Maybe you are trying to upload program while your rx and tx pins are connected with other components.
2. Or maybe your Arduino is bricked.

For the 1st problem solution is just disconnect wires rx,tx and try to upload the sketch. For 2nd problem use another Arduino to upload program on it(SPI connection). You can follow these steps to resolve your issue written in this article:[Programmer is Not Responding Arduino - avrdude: stk500v2_getsync() | Solution](https://www.sheebot.com/2019/07/sketch-not-uploading-through-usb.html)